# Predictable process and supermartingale

Tags: probability-theory

Let $S$ and $T$ be stopping times with $S\leq T$. Define the process $1_{(S,T]}(n,\omega)$ with parameter set $\mathbb{N}$ to be 1 if $S(\omega)<n\leq T(\omega)$, and $0$ otherwise. I am asked to prove that $1_{S,T}$ is predictable/previsible, and deduce that if $X$ is a supermartingale, then

$E(X_{T\wedge n})\leq E(X_{S\wedge n})$ for all $n$.

As for the predictability, this is a matter of showing that $1_{(s,T]}(n,\omega)$ is $\mathcal{F}_{n-1}$-measurable for all $n$. Alternatively, we can show that it is adapted and left-continuous. It seems pretty evident that this function is $\mathcal{F}_n$-measurable, since a characteristic function is measurable iff the set is measurable, and left continuous, since the interval $(S,T]$ is "open to the left side". I reckon the last result is proven by some version of Doobs optional stopping theorem, but I seem to get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Doob's decomposition yields

$$X_n = M_n+A_n+X_0$$ where $(M_n,\mathcal{F}_n)$ is martingale, $M_0=0$ and $A_n$ a decreasing predictable process. Hence

$$\begin{align} X_{T \wedge n}-X_{S \wedge n} &= (M_{T \wedge n}-M_{S \wedge n})+\underbrace{(A_{T \wedge n}-A_{S \wedge n})}_{\stackrel{S \leq T} \leq 0} \\ \Rightarrow \mathbb{E}(X_{T \wedge n}-X_{S \wedge n}) &\leq \mathbb{E}(M_{T \wedge n}-M_{S \wedge n})\stackrel{(\ast)}{=} 0 \end{align}$$

In $(\ast)$ we used that $$\mathbb{E}(M_{S \wedge n}) = \mathbb{E}(M_{T \wedge n}) = \mathbb{E}M_0$$ since $M$ is a martingale and both $S \wedge n$ and $T \wedge n$ are (obviously) bounded stopping times.

(In fact you could also apply Doob's stopping theorem directly. But in this case there is actually nothing to prove.)

Comment: How would Doob's theorem apply directly? Would you apply it to $Y_n = X_{n \wedge S}$?

Comment: @TheSubstitute It depends on which version of the stopping theorem you know. The one I was talking about goes as follows: Let $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a supermartingale and $S \leq T$ any two bounded stopping times, then $$\mathbb{E}(X_T) \leq \mathbb{E}(X_S).$$ Applying this for the two (bounded) stopping times $S \wedge n$ and $T \leq n$, we get $$\mathbb{E}(X_{T \wedge n}) \leq \mathbb{E}(X_{S \wedge n}).$$